# JQuery UI Accordion don't push emelemnts down when height increases

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, height, jquery-ui-accordion

I've made alternative sidebar menu on right, see : http://www.reallifit.com/videos/

I've run into problem when expanding elements. Accordion goes under footer div rather then pushing the content down.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion for possible solution:

Apply a new line in your CSS

```
#content_area{
  min-height:1200px;
}
```

Comment: yes, it is a simple workaround, but I want better solution. :)